# SessionNotCreatedException: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 79 using ChromeDriver and Chrome through Selenium and JavaScript

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

My ChromeDriver is updated to the version of my Chromium (well, not really, its ChromeDriver v89 on Chromium v90), but it keeps giving me this error (shown in title). I was hoping that someone could help fix this.

My code to initialize the driver is:

```js
const {Builder, By, Key, util} = require('selenium-webdriver');
let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
```

(solved)

Comment: how are you pasing the chrome driver path ? check your environment variable and see you are not pointing to older chromedriver

Comment: I have checked, I am not pointing to an older version of ChromeDriver.

Comment: Delete that driver and see if it throws driver not found error , if it doesn then it means its not using that chromedriver

Comment: are you using windows ?

Comment: It doesn't, how do I make it use the new driver? Also, I am

Comment: Looked around and found that I had another webdrivers folder, I moved it to there and I'm still getting the same error lol

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228057/discussion-between-zusk-and-pdhide).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

**Goto details and click chrome driver and click property. it shows the path**

[image]

Now replace that driver with new driver.

Comment: I have, it shows the same error. I'll try updating again I guess

Comment: close all chromedriver process , run your code again and check the new chromedriver process and the location from which it was triggered

Comment: Ah okay, it worked! Now I need to figure out how to get Chrome version 89, any idea on how to do that?

Comment: https://www.google.com/chrome/?brand=CHBD&brand=JJTC&gclid=CjwKCAiApNSABhAlEiwANuR9YD1RVLtosnJveKukwTFiz_7PvTwBpiIwO1y0HKLHKORsutibpXuhihoCKeAQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds

Comment: https://github.com/macchrome/chromium/releases for chromium